# Is carousel display out of fashion?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design

Carousel in web design is used to display a series of (interactive) banners. Is it phasing out-of-fashion, these days?

Microsoft.com and Apple.com still do use it with and without arrows.

Is there a Usability study that verily questions its use /application in design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been many studies of it and the general UX pov is: Don't.

Look at this link for a overview of of carousels, containing further links to studies that came to the conclusion that they're god awful (and a link to a previous discussion on this very site): http://conversionxl.com/dont-use-automatic-image-sliders-or-carousels-ignore-the-fad/

Basically.

1: If you can avoid using them then please do.

2: If you really have to use them then at least make sure they're not automatic.

3: If you really have to use them then it is highly advisable to make sure the navigation is large and clear.

As to whether they are fashionable...that's quite a different issue to whether they are good for user experience. There I would say: Yes, they are very fashionable.

I have to admit in my work I do sometimes use them; they're a good place to put unimportant information that really doesn't have to be viewed on the front page but various stakeholders insist should be on the front page anyway. And they can look rather pretty...even if they're useless from a data sharing POV.

Comment: Marketing departments created them and are, if they're paying attention to their analytics reports, seeing how bad they are.